# Implementing our own network physical layer for fun (e.g. Ethernet) - is it too difficult? what is the suggested approach?

Tags: arduino, filter, network

We are interested in creating our own network stack. For the other layers (application layer ~ link layer), I have done Stanford CS144 and CMU 15-441 so a toy has been implemented. However, I have no idea about how to implement the **physical layer**. We only want to create a *toy*, so things like performance are not a problem.

My naive thought: We can implement the Ethernet protocol in the physical layer. We can use an Arduino board. Some of its pins will be connected to the Ethernet wires. Then we write C++ code (for Arduino) to control the voltage of those pins (thus controlling the data on the wires). The other end of the wire will be connected to a standard commercial device (maybe a switch).

In other words, as a whole, my application-layer HTTP server (already implemented) will talk to my TCP stack and other layers down to link layer (implemented). And my link layer software code (in a Linux machine) will talk to physical layer (in Arduino). Then those high-voltage/low-voltage signals will be transmitted from the pins of Arduino to a normal device (e.g. a switch), and from there we will connect to anywhere in the Internet. Finally, my home-made HTTP server will be able to talk to anyone in the world who wants to see it.

Question: Is my naive thought OK, or not feasible? Will it be too difficult (e.g. I want to implement it within a week, can I)? Are there any easier approaches that you recommend?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Bit-banging 10MBps Ethernet has been done many times already, on a 20MHz AVR. Too difficult and unusable for any practical use as it was transmit only for a minimum length UDP packet. I suggest trying another physical interface. But since you are looking for IP connectivity can be achieved on other interfaces than Ethernet, like SLIP or PPP over serial port.

Comment: You _can_ do this with an FPGA or very specialized types of processor, but not for Ethernet on an Arduino.  You can certainly come up with other physical layers to support IP networking though.

Comment: Which Arduino boards can you use?

Comment: @Justme Wow that sounds promising! We are *not* trying to use it for big things like downloading a video. We can accept very low bandwidth, as long as a HTTP webpage can be served (slowly is ok). So is 10MBps ethernet ok for (slowly) transmitting tcp packets? Thanks! (I will also look at SLIP/PPP but Ethernet seems very widely used so most interesting)

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hmm if with FPGA is it difficult? We have learnt computer architecture and have written some Verilog code, but have not actually played with a FPGA board.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Maybe uno/mega? If needed, maybe we can also use STM32 boards

Comment: I tried https://www.fpga4fun.com/10BASE-T0.html on afternoon around 14 years ago, it got some packets out, but unreliably.   The dodgy idea there of using capacitive coupling rather than a proper transformer may have contributed to the flakiness.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So if we follow the tutorial, and then add a `transformer` at the output pins, will we get better (or reliable) results? In other words, is the tutorial feasible? Thanks!

Comment: It's more a conceptual project, you wouldn't really build a product that way, you'd use a proper Ethernet PHY.  But they do a good job of letting you see inside what's usually a "black box"

Comment: @ChrisStratton Of course we are only building a toy :) I just wonder whether it will have acceptable loss rate. By the way, did you use a Hub or a Switch? [The tutorial](https://www.fpga4fun.com/10BASE-T3.html) itself said that, hubs have lots of drops but switch does not, due to packet collision

Comment: Its unclear when you say "toy" if you mean a "toy" for yourself, or a *product* that is a toy...  As for what I tried 14 years ago I think I tried a few things on the other end of the cable with various success.  I'm pretty sure it was disconnected from the building network, just the FPGA and my PC.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh it is a toy for ourselves, not to be saled. What do you mean by "with various success"?

Comment: @Justme Could you please provide some links/tutorials, since I do not find any... Thanks!

Comment: What you can't find? SLIP? PPP? Bit-bang Ethernet? Unless you are not aware, and are looking for a toy, you can get STM32 Nucleo boards with real 10/100 Ethernet PHY, onboard debugger and sockets for adding other hardware like Arduino shields for a budgetary price of about $19. It's a plug and play wired Ethernet solution, needs no intermediate SLIP/PPP bridge and beats the Arduinos in processing power. And an ESP32 module that provides WiFi connectivity is about $5. You'll spend more trying to build hardware between bit-banging MCU and RJ45 socket and it would be a miracle to get it to work.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4f4OzEyueg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @Justme Thanks for your reply! (1) I did not find things related to the "...has been done many times already, on a 20MHz AVR..." you mentioned (2) I want to create the whole stack by myself for fun (as a toy for myself), so maybe I will not buy those boards with hardware Ethernet included, but may want to create my own... I will look at the STM32 version you mentioned

Comment: @ch271828n I do have to wonder what keywords did you use for searching bit-bang ethernet f you can't find anything relevant.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Looks interesting, thanks!

Comment: @Justme Ha I did not add the "bit-bang" keyword... Silly me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other end of the wire will be connected to a standard commercial device (maybe a switch).

This was the big immediate red flag for the design. Your Arduino will be able to assert voltages of 0 and 5 volts on the wires of the Ethernet connector, at a modest frequency in the kilohertz range. A commercial switch has an Ethernet frontend, which includes magnetics and a particular serial transceiver. Your Arduino won't be able to work with the necessary voltages and frequencies that come through the magnetics (it won't be 0-5 V coming back to your microcontroller), and even with the right analog frontend you almost certainly won't meet the timings that the Ethernet hardware at the other end expects.

Now here's the good news: Arduinos have a number of I/O features, such as SPI, serial ports, etc, in addition to the directly-toggleable I/O pins. None of them will be able to talk to an Ethernet switch if you wired the pins to the Ethernet cable, but you can use them to directly connect Arduinos to each other. Of course, your off-the-shelf switch is no longer an option; this means that you may need to implement a whole "ch271828n-thernet" switch on an Arduino with enough I/O capabilities.

One example that comes immediately to mind is using the serial port (either of the Arduino, of a USB-serial adapter, or even of the serial port in your machine). You can come up with a physical framing layer, such as careful use of [consistent overhead byte stuffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Overhead_Byte_Stuffing). Even better, there was a day when we *did* send Internet packets over a serial port -- the glorious days of dial-up where our computers would encapsulate and frame Internet packets on the serial port using [a simple framing protocol known as SL/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol). As a rather simple protocol you should be able to implement it in a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: Indeed, SLIP was how a few "look at this, a webserver on an 8-pin PIC" type projects were done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! (1) For the ethernet timing requirement, if we buy a switch supporting old version slow ethernet, can we meet the timing? (2) the proposal in 2nd paragraph does not work for us, since we want to do something in the real world (3) we would love to implement things even in the most "bottom", so we may also implement our own Serial port things, maybe by sending out voltage on an Arduino pin. Is that ok?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hi could you please provide some links, since I do not find much information... Thank!

Comment: Sorry but this site isn't a place for requesting links.  Use a web search

Comment: @ch271828n 1. An Arduino will not be able to handle the analog requirements, and it will take far longer than a week to get the timing exactly right *even if* the Arduino were fast enough. 2. Arduinos *are* the real world. It just means that *all* your phys are arduinos, and you don't talk to off-the-shelf Ethernet phys. 3. Yes, in that case you bit-bang the serial. Not sure how experienced you are so I can't say whether you'll be able to do it within a week.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hi sorry that I have tried searched it in Google, without finding related projects...

Comment: @nanofarad Thank you very much!

Comment: @ch271828n https://www.google.com/search?q=slip+arduino

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks! (I originally searched things like "webserver on pic")